Keep getting token expired response on mobile devices
I have a frontend React app that I created using Vite with TypeScript, hosted via Vercel, and an Express app that I'm hosting via Heroku. When a user logs in with their credentials and it is correct, they are redirected to the landing page, which is exactly how it is supposed to be. The backend runs a helper function that sends the authToken:
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const generateTokenAndSetCookie = (user, rememberMe, res) => {
  const SECRET_KEY = process.env.SECRET_KEY;
  if (!SECRET_KEY) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      message: "Internal server error. SECRET_KEY is not defined.",
      success: false,
    });
  }

  const expiresIn = rememberMe ? "7d" : "12h";
  const token = jwt.sign(
    {
      id: user.id,
      email: user.email,
      username: user.name,
    },
    SECRET_KEY,
    { expiresIn },
  );

  res.cookie("authToken", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    sameSite: "none",
    maxAge: rememberMe ? 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 : 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  });

  return token;
};

This works completely fine on desktop. The problem is, because this is an httpOnly: true token, JavaScript can't access this token. That's why, in the response, I'm sending a flag called tokenProvided: true.
return res.status(200).json({
      message: "Login successful!",
      success: true,
      tokenProvided: true,
      username: user.name,
      isVerified: true,
    });

On the frontend, I'm setting that value in a cookie and then navigating the user to the landing page:
Cookies.set("tokenProvided", data.tokenProvided);
navigate("/");

In the LoggedInLandingPage, I have a useEffect hook that checks for tokenProvided. The whole point of this tokenProvided flag was to check if the user was logged in before, and if not, this would prevent useless API calls.
const tokenProvided = Cookies.get("tokenProvided");

const verifyToken = async () => {
    if (!tokenProvided) return

try {
      const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}${AUTH_ENDPOINT}`, {
        withCredentials: true,
      });
} catch (e: any) {
      if(e.response.status === 401 || e.response.status === 403) {
         Cookies.remove("tokenProvided");
      }
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
    verifyToken();
}, [tokenProvided]);


This works as intended on desktop. The problem is, when I tried it with my phone, it kept giving me the same error message, which is "Token expired."
I just want to make sure that I'm handling everything correctly. The backend route to check the token is:
login.get("/auth", authenticateToken, decodeView);

Middleware:
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import "dotenv/config";

const SECRET_KEY = process.env.SECRET_KEY;

const authenticateToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.authToken;

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      success: false,
      message: "No token provided",
    });
  }

  jwt.verify(token, SECRET_KEY, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      res.clearCookie("authToken");
      if (err.name === "TokenExpiredError") {
        return res.status(401).json({
          success: false,
          message: "Session expired. Please log in again.",
        });
      } else if (err.name === "JsonWebTokenError") {
        return res.status(403).json({
          success: false,
          message: "Token invalid",
        });
      } else {
        return res.status(403).json({
          success: false,
          message: "Token verification failed",
        });
      }
    }
    req.user = user;
    next();
  });
};

export default authenticateToken;

decodeView:

export const decodeView = (req, res) => {
  return res.status(200).json({
    decoded: req.user,
    success: true,
  });
};

Why might this token expiration issue occur only on mobile devices, and what steps can I take to resolve it? Is there something specific to mobile environments that I should account for in my token handling or cookie settings?
What I Tried:
I implemented a login flow where a JWT is generated on the backend and set as an httpOnly cookie. This token is then used to authenticate subsequent requests. I tested this on desktop, and everything works as expected. I also added a flag (tokenProvided) in the response to track whether the user is logged in and to manage API calls effectively.
What I Expected:
I expected the same functionality to work on mobile devices as it does on desktop—specifically, the user should be redirected to the landing page after a successful login, and the token should be verified without issues.
What Actually Happened:
On mobile devices, I consistently receive a "Token expired" error when attempting to verify the token, even though the same setup works perfectly on desktop. The token expiration issue seems to be specific to mobile.



Update:
I discovered the issue, and I wanted to share my findings in case anyone else encounters a similar problem.
The problem seems to be related to how cookies are handled, particularly on mobile devices. When setting cookies, certain browsers (especially on mobile) enforce stricter privacy and security policies. If your application doesn't explicitly handle user consent for cookies, the browser might block or restrict certain cookies, particularly those marked as SameSite=None; Secure. This could cause the token to not be stored properly on mobile devices, leading to the "Token expired" error when making requests that rely on the token.
What I suspect is happening:
Stricter Cookie Policies: Modern browsers, especially on mobile, require that cookies with SameSite=None also have the Secure flag and that your site uses HTTPS. While my backend and frontend setups meet these criteria, browsers might still restrict cookies if explicit user consent isn't obtained.
Cookie Consent Requirements:
Some mobile browsers or operating systems may enforce cookie consent policies more strictly, potentially blocking cookies until the user explicitly agrees to their use. Without consent, the authToken cookie may not be stored, causing issues when attempting to verify the user's session.
Testing on Desktop vs. Mobile:
Desktop browsers may be less aggressive in enforcing these policies during testing, which is why everything worked perfectly on desktop but failed on mobile.
Solution:
To address this issue, you should ensure the following:
Implement Cookie Consent:
Use a cookie consent banner to explicitly obtain the user's consent before setting any cookies. This ensures compliance with privacy regulations like GDPR and may prevent cookies from being blocked by the browser.
Verify Cookie Settings: Double-check that your cookies are set with the correct flags:
httpOnly: true
secure: true
sameSite: "none"

Debug Mobile Browsers:
Use browser developer tools on mobile devices to confirm whether the authToken cookie is being set correctly. Look for any warnings or errors related to cookies in the console.
Check Cross-Origin Issues:
If your frontend and backend are on different domains or subdomains, ensure that your cookies are configured for cross-origin requests. This includes setting withCredentials: true on the frontend and properly configuring your backend CORS settings.
Key Takeaway:
The issue was not with the token generation or backend authentication logic but rather with how cookies are handled on mobile devices. Properly configuring cookies and implementing user consent should resolve this problem.
